# React native statusbar styles cannot override native android statusbar style

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to set statusbar translucency to false on componentDidMount but it doesnt seem to work. 
My reasons for doing so are different (*because I am using `react-native-bootsplash` which requires me to have native styles*) but overall it doesn't seem to work.

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>

<style name="BootTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bootsplash</item>
</style>
```

**Login.js**

```
componentDidMount(): void {
    .
    .
    StatusBar.setTranslucent(false);
    StatusBar.setBackgroundColor("#FFF");
}
.
.
.
render() {
    const Navigation = this.props.navigation;

    return (
        <>
            <StatusBar backgroundColor="white" barStyle="dark-content"/>
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define 2 statusbar one of is normal and the other one is translucency. Then, you can control it's situation with state. For example;

```
render() {

    return (

        <View>

            {
                this.state.translucency  ?

                    <View>
                        /* custom style for statusbar */
                        <View style={{backgroundColor: "black", height:statusBarHeight, opacity: 0.3}}/>
                        <StatusBar backgroundColor={statusbarColor} barStyle="light-content" />
                    </View>

                    :

                    <StatusBar />

            }

        </View>

    );

}
```

Comment: I need to have an opaque status bar all the time in my app. So I am not sure if using state is appropriate.

Comment: What I assume is that the statusbar in the render can't override the status bar style set in the native code.

Comment: You can customize your statusbar from react native. Why do you need native side for this? I could not get it.

Comment: I am using react-native-bootsplash for splash screen for which I need to set some styles in the native code. Also I want the splash screen to be full screen but using fullscreen flags and cutoutdisplay flags keeps a dark bar at the top in notched devices. To workaround that issue, I am trying our a different solution for which I need to set the status bar transluceny and colour manually.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can use this I think. If you cannot, I couldn't find other solution for this.

Comment: That might be a solution but can you tell me why `setTranslucent` doesn't work?

Comment: statusbar already rendered in componentDidmount and you try to change it's props after render. I am not sure but that's why the reason. have you tried to call StatusBar.setTranslucent(false); in componentWillmount that calls before render?

Comment: Nopes I havent tried. Let me try and see. AFAIK, componentWillMount has been deprecated.

Comment: I tried with both `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` and `componentWillMount` but with no effect.